# Passing a password variable with a ! character to sysadminctl with escapes?

Tags: terminal

Let's say I have a password abc!!!!123 for an admin account with a ST (Secure Token) that I need to pass thru sysadminctl to grant another admin account a ST. I already have the abc!!!!123 in a variable: $ST_admin_Pass. Here's the statement in my sh script:

```
/usr/sbin/sysadminctl -secureTokenOn "$temp_Admin" -password "$temp_Admin_Pass" -adminUser "$ST_admin" -adminPassword "$ST_admin_Pass"
```

where $temp_Admin is the account to be granted the ST and $ST_admin is the account that has a ST.

Running this command in a sh script fails and I am assuming it is because of the ! in the password, since running the same statement from the command line with the password's ! un-escaped fails:

```
/usr/bin/sysadminctl -secureTokenOn temp_admin -password SomePassword -adminUser adminwithST -adminPassword abc!!!!123
```

but escaping the ! works:

```
/usr/bin/sysadminctl -secureTokenOn temp_admin -password SomePassword -adminUser adminwithST -adminPassword abc\!\!\!\!123
```

Should I add escapes to the variable? If so, what is the proper way of doing that? Is there a way to pass the variable so that it doesn't need escapes?

Comment: Double-quotes around the variable reference should be all you need or want. Are you *sure* the variable has the correct value? Note that `echo "$ST_admin_Pass"` is not a good way to test this.

Comment: Can you add the actual error you get? And switch the password to one without !!! temporary to see whether it's actually the !!! causing the issue?

Comment: @GordonDavisson On interactive use `!!` also get replaced within double quotes (just type `cd`, ENTER, `"!!"` in `bash`). But in a script it shouldn't actually matter.

Comment: @nohillside `!!` only gets replaced if it's directly part of the command line, not if it's part of a referenced variable's value. So `-adminPassword "$ST_admin_Pass"` should work either interactively or in a script.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ah, right :-) Actually `-adminPassword $ST_admin_Pass` does as well **in this case**.